# Data Structure to sort elements by values

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, associative-array

I need a data structure in Java that can manipulate `String`s, compute the frequency of each word in an `ArrayList<String>` and then I need to sort them based on the frequencies.

To put it simply, the data structure needs to be an **associative array**, that can be sorted **BY VALUES** , I already put the lines into the `HashMap` and got surprised by the fact **that it can't be sorted** , now I'm stuck thinking about another data structure.

P.S. (using two lists is not suited to my program because it needs to do a lot of calculations, so it would be better if a single structure holds each `String` and its occurence instead of a list for the `String`s and annother for the frequency).

EDIT: I appreciate the help, but some people are suggesting a `TreeMap`, so I want to specify something here: I need the structure sorted by the occurences of the strings (in the case of `Map`s it would be the values not the keys).

Comment: Use TreeMap instead of HashMap

Comment: well, imho OP is giving the question quite clear:  He want an associative array with String as key and frequency as value, for which it will be sorted base on the frequency.  Quite interesting to me actually

Comment: @hemena314 My code uses a hash map which can't be sorted , that's why i didn't show it,i think i made it very  clear what i'm trying to do (counting the occurence of strings and then sort based on the occurences )

Comment: @hamena i only need guidance for  a data structure that can be sorted ...also i'm not someone who just wants his work done for him here , i don't want programming guidance because my question is conceptual ...but thanks anyway

Comment: who said hashmap can't be sorted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple data structure for this.

The frequencies are changing when you are collecting the frequency data.  For which sorting should comes after the all string frequencies are collected.

The easiest way I can think of is:

```
// psuedo-code
final Map<String, Integer> stringFreq = ....; // it doesn't matter what kind of impl you use

// collect the String vs frequency in stringFreq

Map<String, Integer> result = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(stringFreq, 
        new Comparator<String> {
        @Override
            public int compare(String a, String b) {
                int aFreq = stringFreq.get(a);
                int bFreq = stringFreq.get(b);
                return (aFreq==bFreq)?a.compareTo(b) : (aFreq-bFreq);
            }
        });


// result should have data sorted by frequency, and then the string value
```

Answer (score 4):

`HashMap` isn't sorted, actually and shouldn't be so. If you want to have entries sorted, you may use one of `SortedMap` implementations, for example, `TreeMap`.

`TreeMap` has a constructor, which helps you in case you have non-standard `Comparator` (for example, if you want natural sorting for `String`s):

```
TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator)
```

**UPD**: I missed the point, that you need to sort entries by value.

In this case, I don't see any solution, except for the one, in which you'll have to sort entries only several times, but not to keep this state.

You may use any `Map`, for example, stay with `HashMap`, but then, before processing, you may sort the entries:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = map.entrySet();
Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sorted = new TreeSet<>(
        Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue).reversed()); // it's Java 8, but you may extract this lambda
sorted.addAll(entries);
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: sorted) {
    //...
    // the entries will be sorted by value
}
```

To be precise, you can't you any kind of `Map` to maintain entries sorted this way, because order of keys is set only once and you can't change it, because of:

1. This is not-conventional, `Comparator`/`compareTo` operator should give the same result over the run (that's why mutable classes are not appreciated in `Map`s)
2. This is not expected to give you some appreciable result, the keys are not re-sorted generally.

Comment: Much better solution than LinkedHashMap

Comment: Please read again what OP is asking for: TreeMap is going to sort base on the key, but OP is asking for something that will sort base on the value (frequency)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using a custom bean and a simple list.

1/ Define your custom bean

```
public class StringOccurence {
  String string ;
  int occurrence ;
}
```

2/ Create a comparator

```
public class StringOccurrenceComparator implements Comparator<StringOccurence> {
  @Override
  public int compare(StringOccurrence so1, StringOccurrence so2) {
    return Integer.compare(so1.occurrence, so2.occurrence);
  }
}
```

3/ Sort you list using the comparator

```
List<StringOccurrence> list = constructList();
Collections.sort(list, new StringOccurrenceComparator());
```

If you are luckily enough to use java8, here is a short version of the point 2 and 3:

```
List<StringOccurrence> list = constructList();
Collections.sort(list, (so1, so2) -> Integer.compare(so1.occurrence, so2.occurrence));
```

Comment: The bean is called StringOccurence but the Comparator and List generic type is StringFrequency

Comment: @sharonbn I really need more coffee... Thank's ;)

Answer (score 0):

Java has a [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) interface with two implementations.  The easiest one being [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Comment: Please read again what OP is asking for: TreeMap is going to sort base on the key, but OP is asking for something that will sort base on the value (frequency)

Comment: That is not specified in the question.  The frequency could be the key?

Comment: it is mentioned in the question.  Please read it carefully :)  `compute the frequency of each word in an ArrayList(of Strings) and then i need to sort it based on the frequencies`.  Using frequency as key is not going to work too (reason is obvious)

Comment: sharonbon , thanks for the help , but i'm afraid Adrian Shum understands what i'm saying here , i need something equivalent to HashMapthat can be sorted by values .

Comment: now, that you edited your question, its much clearer.  don't be surprised why it got downvoted in its previous form

Answer (score 0):

How about if you used a maxheap data structure to store the string and its frequency occurrence value and always kept the max value frequency at the top,then you can simply get the one with the maximum frequency at one go,but the complexity here would be to re-calculate and adjust the max heap so really depends on what kind of change you expect to see more-more number of words or highly changing frequency of words.